# Vue routing redirect from path '/' to another page if a condition is met

Tags: redirect, vuejs3, url-routing

I have a Login page that is bound to the path `'/'`. And if I login, I go to `'/home'`. The problem is that if I manually type the path `'/'` in the url of the browser, I go to the login page again. Is there a way to redirect me to `'/home'` if am already logged in? I know that I can use redirect like in the code below, but I am not sure where should I declare the a variable called `isLoggedIn` and how to use it. Or maybe it could be better do it in the `<script>` section of the `Login` page.

```
{
   path: '/',
   name: 'Login',
   component: Login,
   redirect: to => {
       return {path: '/orders'}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `navigation guard` :

you will find more information in the vue router documentation https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

And here is a quick example extracted from this page

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
  if (
    // make sure the user is authenticated
    !isAuthenticated &&
    // ❗️ Avoid an infinite redirect
    to.name !== 'Login'
  ) {
    // redirect the user to the login page
    return { name: 'Login' }
  }
})
```